# Enable http2 on Azure Web App MVC application requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, http2

I am trying to enable http2 protocol on a Azure Web app, MVC application without any luck. The tutorial is simple just activate the 2.0 in Application settings of the portal, Http2 online tests states that the http2 protocol is enabled, no requests is on http2.

Https is enabled, minimum tls version set to 1.2... any ideas on what can go wrong?

Comment: Try using other methods as described here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/04/13/announcing-http2-support-in-azure-app-service/ 
 also check the browser compatibility.

Comment: What problem are you facing now? Protocol is http2 but no request on http2?

Comment: @Ashok I've tried, i've also tried with brand new hello world projects, but still no http2 request

Comment: @JoeyCai, tools like https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test state that the protocol is enabled on the server, but still no request  on the http2 protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that an antivirus on my computer was the root cause for all the requests still being on the http. After i disabled it the requests were, as expected on http2.